# Monogame: no sound effects until DirectX reinstalled.

Tags: directx, monogame

Environment: Windows 10 (fresh install), using Monogame 3.6 (same goes for  3.5 for this matter) on DirectX projects.
Problem: I can’t hear any sound effect unless I reinstall DirectX.

Before reinstalling DirectX, there is no exception or status information I could use to trace why the sound is not audible. After reinstalling, it just works. Same code, even same binary.

I don’t want my users to have to reinstall DX. This will be awkward as Win10 comes with DX pre-installed.

So I wonder if someone knows which additional DX libraries I may include in project folder so that the sound effects are audible without reinstalling DX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand that you cannot "Install DirectX" on Windows 10 or any version of Windows back to Windows XP Service Pack 2. The *DirectX End-User Runtime* package (a.k.a `DXSETUP`) doesn't actually install Direct3D, DirectPlay, DirectSound, etc. It doesn't even include the CABs needed to install DirectX on older versions of Windows.

[Not So Direct Setup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup/)

The version of "DirectX" installed is only ever updated via Windows Update, installing a new version of Windows, or some kind of Service Pack. Windows 10 includes all supported components of DirectX 9.0c, DirectX 10.x, DirectX 11.x, and DirectX 12.0 as part of the OS.

[Direct3D 11 Deployment for Game Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416644.aspx)

What the *DirectX End-User Runtime* package does install is the various legacy side-by-side helper components: D3DX9, D3DX10, D3DX12, XAUDIO2.7 or earlier, XINPUT 1.3 or earlier, XACTENGINE, and the legacy Managed DirectX 1.1 assemblies. That's it.  Furthermore, it installs about 100 MB of these things including every version that has ever shipped for both x86 and x64, which means your game is **never going to use most of them**. Likely Monogame is set up to use XAudio 2.7 which is the last version of XAudio to support Windows 7. As such, it needs just a handful of CABs from DXSETUP.

[KB179113: How to install the latest version of DirectX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/179113/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-directx)
[XAudio2 and Windows 8](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8/)

Finally, the DXSETUP files that shipped in the end-of-life DirectX SDK (June 2010) are actually *not* the latest version of the *DirectX End-User Runtime*. I fixed a number of bugs in an online only April 2011 refresh.

[DXSETUP Update](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2011/04/19/dxsetup-update/)